# How would I query nested JSON data values in SQL using json_extract()?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Mysql version is 6.7+

Example of the column I need to get a value from below.

`json_extract(goal_templates.template_data, group_concat('$.resources'))`
->This results in a NULL return for all rows.

| :template_data |
| --- |
| `{"Resolve housing issues": {"tasks": [{"name": "Use Decision Map to explore paths to resolving'' housing issue", "end_date": "15 days", "taskType": 3, "help_text": "", "resources": [], "start_date": "today", "actionOrder": "1", "recur_every": "", "resource_reference_id": ""}, {"name": "Select a local Debt & Credit Counseling Service", "end_date": "15 days", "taskType": 3, "help_text": "Add & tag local Credit & Debt Counseling Service (Organization)", "resources": ["14579", "14580"], "start_date": "today", "actionOrder": "2", "recur_every": "", "resource_reference_id": "14579, 14580"}, {"name": "[Schedule Credit & Debt Counseling as SGE or RGE]", "end_date": "15 days", "taskType": 3, "help_text": "", "resources": [], "start_date": "today", "actionOrder": "3", "recur_every": "", "resource_reference_id": ""}, {"name": "Rate resource for benefit of those who follow", "end_date": "15 days", "taskType": 3, "help_text": "", "resources": [], "start_date": "today", "actionOrder": "4", "recur_every": "", "resource_reference_id": ""}], "sequence_num": "1"}}` |

Comment: Ignore the group_concat() as I can see how that wouldn't work. I still don't understand how I would retrieve the $.resources values only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `JSON_EXTRACT` to extract a key from the `JSON_COLUMN` using the following syntax:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(json_field, '$.key')
```

If, however, we need to extract nested keys like in your case, we can either append the nested child keys to the path like

```
JSON_EXTRACT('{"resolve_housing_issues": {"tasks": [{"name": "Decision Map", "end_date": "15 days"}]}}', '$.resolve_housing_issues.tasks[0].name')
```

as is depicted in @bill-karwin's answer or make use of the wildcards like the following:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"resolve_housing_issues": {"tasks": [{"name": "Decision Map", "end_date": "15 days"}]}}', '$**.resolve_housing_issues') as resolve_housing_issues;
```

It produces the following result:

[image: Extracing the value of child key]

While the query

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"resolve_housing_issues": {"tasks": [{"name": "Decision Map", "end_date": "15 days"}]}}', '$**.tasks') as tasks;
```

produces the following result:

[image: Extracting the value of sub-child key]

So on and so forth.

More on this can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths).

Answer (score 3):

The selector I was looking for seems to be a "$**" wildcard. This allowed me to grab all of the unnamed objects for each of the rows and the values of the nested resources.

`JSON_EXTRACT(template_data, '$**.tasks[*].resources') AS resources`

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select json_extract(template_data, '$."Resolve housing issues".tasks[*].resources') as resources from goal_templates;
+----------------------------------+
| resources                        |
+----------------------------------+
| [[], ["14579", "14580"], [], []] |
+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: That seems to work wonderfully! Thank you Bill.

I have a follow-up question though.

What would the syntax look like if instead of specifying "Resolve housing issues" object, I wanted to get the same result for all of the rows in the table?

Comment: I tried something like this and MySQL workbench didn't like the expression.

```json_extract(template_data, '$[*].tasks[*].resources')```

Comment: Probably something involving [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg). But let me make a suggestion: if you don't know how to code expressions with JSON data on your own, you should really consider not storing data in JSON format. Use normal columns and rows.